# Having trouble call a method from another class

Tags: java

My assignment is to create an address book and there are multiple classes. I'm having trouble figuring out how to call a method from a class that does not contain the main method. So that you know what I'm asking, here is a list of the classes I need to have in my program:

- `BaseContact` (generic info, name, number, etc)
- `Person` (info specific to a person)
- `Business` (info specific to a business)
- `Location` (address: building number, street, city, state, zip)
- `Photo` (photo ID number, file name, date of photo, and description)
- `AddressBook` (Contains list of all Contacts. Methods neede: add, remove, display one, sort, and search for contacts by any of the properties of the contacts.
- `DataAccessService` – This class will have methods to readAllContacts and saveAllContacts. Implement this class as an interface.
- `FileAccessService` – This will implement the DataAccessService interface. The contacts will be saved to a text file and read from a text file.
- `DatabaseAccessService` – This will also implement the DataAccessService interface. The contacts will be read and written to a table in a SQL database.
- `ConsoleApp` – Has a main() method. In main(), you can create instances of the other classes in the application.

Below is the code, so far, for the classes I'm inquiring about

**`BaseContact` class:**

```
Public class BaseContact {
        private String phoneNumber;
        private String name;

    public BaseContact(String phoneNumber, String Name) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {return phoneNumber;}

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {this.phoneNumber = 
                               phoneNumber;}

    public String getName() {return name;}

    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    }
```

**`PersonContact` Class:**

```
public class PersonContact extends BaseContact {
private String dob;
private String description;

public PersonContact(String dob, String description, String phoneNumber, String name) {
    super(phoneNumber, name);
    this.dob = dob;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDob() {return dob;}

public void setDob(String dob) {this.dob = dob;}

public String getDescription() {return description;}

public void setDescription(String description) {this.description = description;}
```

}

**`BusinessContact` Class:**

```
public class BusinessContact extends BaseContact {
private String busHours;
private String website;

public BusinessContact(String busHours, String website, String phoneNumber, String name) {
    super(phoneNumber, name);
    this.busHours = busHours;
    this.website = website;
}

public String getBusHours() {return busHours;}

public void setBusHours(String busHours) {this.busHours = busHours;}

public String getWebsite() {return website;}

public void setWebsite(String website) {this.website = website;}
```

}

**`Location` Class:**

```
public class Location {
private String buildingNum;
private String additionalAddr;
private String street;
private String city;
private String state;
private int zip;

public Location(String buidingNum, String additionalAddr, String street, String city, String state, int zip) {
    this.buildingNum = buildingNum;
    this.additionalAddr = additionalAddr;
    this.street = street;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.zip = zip;
}
```

}

**`Photo` Class:**

```
public class Photo {
private String idNumber;
private String fileName;
private String photoDate;
private String description;
```

}

I understand that I will just extend the `BaseContact` class in the `PersonContact` and `BusinessContact` classes, but I'm not sure how to link the `Photo` and `Location` classes to the contacts. Will I be calling the `Location` and `Photo` classes from the `BaseContact` class or from the `PersonContact` and `BusinessContact` classes? Once I do that, how do I pair locations with the correct contact?

Comment: Is `Photo` a kind of `Business`, so a kind of `Contact`? Or just a part of `Business` contact?

Comment: The properties in the location and photo classes will need to be used in both the person and business classes. I wasn't sure if that meant I needed to call the location class from the base class or in both the person and business classes. The directions are not very clear, but I'm assuming the photo and and location classes will have a scanner to input the photo and location data, or I might just make a list for testing purposes first.

Comment: `will need to be **used in** both the person and business`. You got your answer. `Photo` is **a part of** `Business`

Comment: I just edited my post it was supposed to say that I need help linking the photo and location classes to my contact classes. sorry!

Comment: the same way you link the description to the photo

Comment: I guess the real question is, how do I call the location class from the Person and Business classes, like what is the code that I need to use. So far in my class we have only learned how to extend super classes to sub classes (So baseContact to PersonContact and BusinessContact)...we haven't linked additional classes that aren't considered sub classes..or are they?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your instincts are good:  it makes sense that a `Person` would be a type of `BaseContact`, as well as a `Business`.  Try thinking about each of the other classes in turn:  Is a `Location` a type of contact?  Or something that belongs to a contact?  Does a `Person` have a `Photo`?  Does a `Business`?

Something that could be considered part of or "owned by" another class could perhaps be member data for that class.  Another aspect to think through is whether a class can contain only one of something, or any number of them.  (I hope your instructor is introducing the basics of Java's generic collections!)

I hope this gives you a start on figuring out how to handle this assignment.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So, since location and photo classes are not types of contacts, then they would definitely not be subclasses of the BaseContact, therefore, I would not be extending the BaseContact class in the Location and Photo classes. So then does my BaseContact call on the Location and Photo classes to bring in the location/photo data or would I need to call on the Location and Photo classes in both the person and business contacts individually?

Comment: The concept I think you need is "a Person has a Location, and may have a Photo".  To me, that seems to imply that there ought to be a "private Location location;" member, either in PersonContact or, if both a person and a business can have a location, in the base class.  Same goes for Photo.